# iis redirect http to https does not process outbound rules

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, http-headers

Windows Server 2008R2/IIS 7.5. I have a rule to redirect all http requests to https as follows:

```
    <rule name="HTTPS Redirect">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

This has been working perfectly, as expected. Now for PCI compliance, our ASV requires that the server type/version is not displayed in http headers. So I added this outbound rule:

```
  <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
    <rule name="Response Server">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SERVER" pattern=".+" />
        <action type="Rewrite" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
```

This works great for https requests to the server, the `Server:` header is blank, as expected:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK =>
Cache-Control => private
Content-Length => 13049
Content-Type => text/html
Server =>
X-Frame-Options => DENY
Strict-Transport-Security => max-age=31536000;
Date => Tue, 12 Jun 2018 18:41:59 GMT
Connection => close
```

But for http requests, the server header is returned with the redirect:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently =>
Content-Type => text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location => https://www.example.com/
Server => Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Strict-Transport-Security => max-age=31536000;
Date => Tue, 12 Jun 2018 18:44:50 GMT
Connection => close
Content-Length => 151
```

`outboundRules` appears to not be processing. How can I remove the `Server:` header under all circumstances?

Comment: Okay, per the Microsoft URL Rewrite reference, this is why the above code is not working:
[Usage of a **Redirect** action implies that no subsequent rules evaluated for the current URL after redirection is performed.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rewrite-rule-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the previous answer I had here. Turns out that adding a custom header with the name `Server:` does **not** fix the issue. It fools [some tools](http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php), but not all of them. Not even the simple JavaScript one that I created to dump the headers from an Ajax call.

My final solution was to use a Native-Code module called [StripHeaders](https://www.dionach.com/blog/easily-remove-unwanted-http-headers-in-iis-70-to-85#configuration). Full source code, plus a MSI installer, is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Dionach/StripHeaders/).